# Could you please improve/shorten my JavaScript code for my son's 10th birthday?

Tags: javascript, do-while

My son is turning 10 and he's learning JavaScript.
I am creating a birthday tarp for him and I want to use my below code. Do you think you can short it?
Your input will be highly appreciated.

In my tarp, I will get rid of  and

```js
let age = 10, ten = 10;
while (true) {
  if (age == ten) {
    alert('Happy 10th Birthday, son!');
    break;
  } else {
    age++;
  }
}
```

Comment: `alert('Happy 10th Birthday, son!');` is the short version of your code.

Comment: Which can be further shortened to `alert('Happy 10th Birthday, son!')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for something succinct but decorative, perhaps

```
let age = 0; // birthdate mm/dd/yyyy
while (age < 10) {
  age++
}
alert(`Happy ${age}th birthday, son!`);
```

The  `while` condition keeps getting tested until it returns false; so it'll keep running as long as `age` is less than 10. Its last iteration happens at `age == 9`:  9 is less than 10, so it calls `age++`, now age is 10.  It tries the `why` condition again, age is 10, so no longer less than 10, so it skips ahead to the `alert`.

Here's a runnable example with a lot more detail so you can see what it's doing:

```js
let age = 0; 

// Pulling "age < 10" out into a function, so it can log what it's doing:
let checkAge = (age) => {
  console.log(`Checking if ${age} < 10: ${age < 10}`);
  return age < 10;
}


while (checkAge(age)) {
  console.log(`Will add 1 to ${age}`);
  age++;
  console.log(`Age is now ${age}`);
}
console.log(`Happy ${age}th birthday, son!`);
```

Comment: Super! This is great. Thank you, Daniel.

Comment: Hello Daniel, please excuse my ignorance but may I know why the value of age becomes 10? Based on what I have understood,  as long as the value of age is less than 10, keep looping.  So   9 + 1 = 10; less than 10? false, stop looping

Comment: Certainly!  I added more detailed explanation in the answer above.  (Happy birthday to your son, by the way!  I think this is a really nifty thing you're doing)

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for the detailed explanation, Daniel. In fact, I can't thank you enough. I am grateful beyond words.

Comment: More than happy to help! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

```
let age = 10;
while (true) {
  if (age === 10) alert('Happy 10th Birthday, son!');
  else age++;
}
```

Comment: That's an infinite loop.

Comment: this program will never stop

Comment: It is for a banner

Comment: It's just for the tarpaulin texts. Yeah, it's an infinite loop.

Comment: But only have TWO spaces in the indentation!!! ;)

Comment: @connexo I'm sure his 10 year old son would appreciate an exit if statement checking if he's dead on his birthday cake.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this? Happy new year for your son :')

```
let age = 0;
while (age < 10) {
    age++;
}
alert('Happy 10th Birthday, son!');
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, Ivan. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The age variable is set to 10 so you could remove the loop entirely to have something like this:

```
alert("Happy 10th Birthday, son!")
```

If you want to keep the loop, then why not adding a console.log to see the age increasing?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I will make it simpler and go with these codes:

```
let age = 10;

if (age === 10) alert("Happy Birthday, son!");
else age++;
```

Comment: `let age = 10; if (age === 10) ...` the `if` obviously is just useless, just as the `else` is...